# Usage of dollar sign in putStrLn function

Tags: haskell

This is a simple program I wrote.

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main = do
  (fileName1:_) <- getArgs
  contents <- readFile fileName1
  let myList = lines contents
      totalLines = length myList
  putStrLn $ "Total lines in the files are " ++ show (totalLines) ++ " lines"
```

If I remove the dollar sign in the last line, Haskell complains that there is an error. Can anyone please explain me internally what happens with and without the dollar sign (or brackets).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is an operator that passes the value on its right to the function on its left. Here's how it's implemented:

```
f $ x = f x
```

It's useful because it has a very low *operator precedence*, so that in your example, the `++` operators get applied first, resulting in a string that the `$` function takes and passes to `putStrLn`.

Without `$` in your example, Haskell will try to evaluate the line in this order:

```
(putStrLn "Total lines in the files are ") ++ show (totalLines) ++ " lines"
```

So it will try to print the first string, then take the result of `putStrLn` and concatenate it with the other strings, which results in an error since `putStrLn` doesn't return a string.